# PHP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in Seperate filesystem

Tags: php, apache, permission-denied, user-permissions

This may or may not be a duplicate question, partly because the destination folder it's trying to write to, is on a Windows filesystem. I have a script which has a mkdir php function in it, which is trying to create a folder and a file to a mounted windows file system.

Permission on the file

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache 24850 Jan  6 11:31 fns.php

Permission on the folder is

```
drwxr-xr-x.   8 a-linux-user root        0 Dec 29 15:55 ACT!
```

I have the file system mounted on 
 /media/shared

I'm getting a `mkdir(): Permission denied error`. I was wondering where I should start debugging the issue.

My httpd.conf file has this permission:

```
User apache 
Group apache
```

the line or the fstab is

```
//domain.com/shared /media/shared cifs uid=a-linux-user,credentials=/home/some-dir/.creds,domain=GRM,comment=systemd.au‌​tomount 0 0
```

Comment: Apache is trying to write to a location it doesn't have permissions to write to. Start debugging by learning how to assign permissions to users and groups needing particular permissions for particular locations.

Comment: check the path and the write permissions

Comment: What are the args you supplied to `mount` or in `fstab`?

Comment: you've mounted a windows share in linux? Then you have to make sure that the share isn't read-only, that the user account used to access the share has write permissions on both the share AND the underlying file system, blah blah blah

Comment: Can you access this location from the console as your normal user?

Comment: The permissions tell us that only 1 user has the necessary access rights: a-linux-user (and all root users too). So the first step on debugging would be to figure out which user tries to perform the mkdir. If you did not execute a php file in a shell/dos-box it will be the user which is running the webserver. Please check the Taskmanager.

Comment: @prodigitalson the line or the fstab is //domain.com/shared    /media/shared        cifs uid=a-linux-user,credentials=/home/some-dir/.creds,domain=GRM,comment=systemd.automount 0 0

Comment: @ Marc B: I'm able to create folder from command line to the mounted drive

Comment: @unixmiah: to ping someone with a notification message, don't put spaces in handles. You can type the '@' symbol, a few letters, then use tab completion, to help you get it right.

Comment: Please add the `fstab` contents into the question, to save someone having to trawl through comments to discover the current state of the question.

Comment: @Marc B I think it might be the web server user trying to write to the shared folder might be the issue. I'm guessing php is using apache user and the shared drive I have doesn't belong to that group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your apache -> conf -> httpd.conf file & change User and Group from daemon to your machine owner name. (in your case: a-linux-user) See if that works.

Comment: you mean machine hostname being localhost?